# How to find all features in one table that intersect features in another table in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point-in-polygon

I have two tables, `boundary` polygon table and `location` point table. I need to find all `boundary` polygons that contain at least 1 `location` point. What is the proper way to do this in PostGIS?

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM boundary, location
WHERE ST_Intersects(boundary.geom, location.geom)
```

But this returns each combination of `boundary` and `location` that intersect, when all I want is the `boundary` returned once. For example, I got 76 results, but only have 10 `boundary` entries. Do you know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would be more efficient with EXISTS I think since it can stop after first positive. Though Martin's answer should work as well

```sql
SELECT boundary.*
  FROM boundary
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT location.geom 
   FROM location 
    WHERE ST_Intersects(boundary.geom,location.geom) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (boundary.id) boundary.*
FROM boundary, location
WHERE ST_Intersects (boundary.geom, location.geom)
```