# Testing for one or more intersections

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am interested in creating a list of all the IDs from Table_A and whether or not they intersect with any of the geometries from Table_B.

The following would work:

```
SELECT Table_A.id, bool_and(st_intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_B.geom)
FROM Table_A, Table_B
GROUP BY Table_A.id
```

The problem is that this means checking every geometry in Table_A against every geometry in Table_B which is very intensive. How do you query until you find the first intersect, return `TRUE` and then move onto the next geometry in Table_A?

The extension to this, is to then check each row in Table_A for an intersect in several other tables, with the result as follows:

```
Table_A_ID | Table_B_Intersects | Table_C_Intersects | ...
0001       | True               | False              | ...         
...        |  ...               | ...                | ...
```

This answer [How to find all features in one table that intersect features in another table in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92874/how-to-find-all-features-in-one-table-that-intersect-features-in-another-table-i]) from comments helps with the single case, but I cannot see how to apply it in this instance.

Edit: moved from comment, tried the following, but crashes pgAdmin:

```
 SELECT Table_A.id,
 (CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT st_intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_B.geom))
 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS Table_B_Intersects,
 (CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT st_intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_C.geom))
 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS Table_C_Intersects,
 ...
 FROM Table_A, Table_B, Table_C, ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all features in one table that intersect features in another table in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92874/how-to-find-all-features-in-one-table-that-intersect-features-in-another-table-i)

Comment: As usual, I've oversimplified my example, the duplicate indeed answer the original question. Question edited to reflect additional complexity.

Comment: Using CASE as well as EXISTS might be a way forward. Unfortunately the following crashes when I execute it in pgadmin:

    SELECT
    Table_A.id,
    (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT st_intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_B.geom)) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS Table_B_Intersects,
    (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT st_intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_C.geom)) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS Table_C_Intersects,
    ...
    FROM
    Table_A, Table_B, Table_C, ...

Comment: Please edit the existing question instead of adding to the comments. It makes it a lot more readable. And while you are at it, correct the spelling mistakes in the original question as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question, you want to compare TableA to a number of other tables and see which row from TableA intersects with any row of the other tables.

I would proceed with the following query:

```
SELECT 
  Table_A.id, 
  bool_or(Table_B.geom IS NOT NULL) AS Table_B_Intersects ,
  bool_or(Table_C.geom IS NOT NULL) AS Table_C_Intersects 
FROM Table_A 
LEFT JOIN Table_B ON ST_Intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_B.geom)
LEFT JOIN Table_C ON ST_Intersects(Table_A.geom, Table_C.geom)
GROUP BY Table_A.id
```

I don't know if the planner is smart enough to stop when the first bool_or condition is positive but when your tables are properly indexed (are they?!) this shouldn't take ridiculously long. Personally, I would be in favour of using a `count` instead of `bool_or` so you also get a sense of how often it overlaps.

Comment: Frequency of overlap may not be useful in all situations, and going the count route means checking against every geometry in every table. In this case I am testing whether parcels of land are subject to various environmental designations, a yes/no answer is sufficient.

Comment: tables are indexed (gist)

Comment: Did the query in the answer help you? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Well I'm having a go. "Shouldn't take ridiculously long" - what sort of order of magnitude should I be expecting with around 60,000 rows in the first table. Other tables range from 50 to 20000 rows. Minutes? Hours? Days?

Comment: Should be done by now but it also depends how many tables are involved.

Comment: Nope, and I've only tried it with two tables, approx 60000 rows against 30 rows, to start with.

Comment: That should take seconds.. at max. Can you add the output of an `explain analyze` of this query to the question?